# yii2 gridview tree

Tags: php, yii2

**Будьте любезны, подскажите**

Расширения для древовидного отображения таблицы

Наподобие: http://prnt.sc/avlmjk

**Благодарю за ответы**

Comment: https://github.com/leandrogehlen/yii2-treegrid